# Textareas and input texts css

Tags: html, css

I've noticed whenever I set `width: 100%;` on a textarea or an input text, they surpass the parent width. 
[image]

The textarea and text field are surrounded by a padding of 10 pixels within it's container. Is there a way to have it stop once it hits the bounding box surrounding it? What are the best practices to making a `width:100%;` element?

Comment: Awesome! That did the trick too!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest a css reset:

```
textarea, input {
     padding: 0;
     margin: 0;
}
```

and also keep in mind that `width:100%` will match the parent width, but then borders are to be taken into consideration. You may want to learn about `box-sizing` in this article:

http://paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/

Comment: Amazing! I was looking for box-sizing, just didn't know it was called that! Thank you!

Comment: you are welcome! don't forget to read about browser support for it, in case you have to cater for legacy browsers